# `git show` giving confusing results on merge commits

Tags: git

I have always understood `git show` to never show a diff on a merge commit. Probably for the same reason `git log -p` doesn't show a diff on merge commits. However, I am able to create two reproducible scenarios: A merge commit that *does* produce a diff with `git show` and one that does not. I would like to understand why the behavior of `git show` is different between these scenarios.

First, here is a script I ran which creates the repository required to observe the two scenarios above:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -ex

git init test_repo
cd test_repo

# master (commit 1)
printf "one\n" > file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -m one

# master (commit 2)
printf "two\n" >> file.txt
git commit -am two

# master (commit 3)
printf "three\n" >> file.txt
git commit -am three

# topic1 (commit 1)
git checkout -b topic1 @^
printf "four\n" >> file.txt
git commit -am four

# merge topic1 to master (commit 4)
git checkout master
git merge - || true # conflict
printf "one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\n" > file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit --no-edit
git tag merge1 # tag so we can refer to it in examples

# master (commit 5)
printf "five\n" >> file.txt
git commit -am five

# topic2 (commit 1)
git checkout -b topic2
printf "six\n" >> file.txt
git commit -am six

# merge topic2 to master (commit 6)
git checkout master
git merge --no-edit - # no conflict
git tag merge2 # tag so we can refer to it in examples
```

Scenario 1: `git show` shows a diff:

```
$ cd test_repo
$ git show merge1
commit cb7aba11aed80917e3fac64e60aef3fe0a27e5de (tag: merge1)
Merge: 75bae65 5f63df7
Author: John Doe <john.doe@domain.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 19 14:05:34 2019 -0500

    Merge branch 'topic1'

    # Conflicts:
    #       file.txt

diff --cc file.txt
index 4cb29ea,87a123c..f384549
--- file.txt
+++ file.txt
@@@ -1,3 -1,3 +1,4 @@@
  one
  two
 +three
+ four
```

Scenario 2: `git show` does *not* show a diff:

```
$ cd test_repo
$ git show merge2
commit 5f37be9b563afc9c9f43ad04198d80809e6fc13a (HEAD -> master, tag: merge2)
Merge: 6f4cf36 bde33e8
Author: John Doe <john.doe@domain.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 19 14:05:34 2019 -0500

    Merge branch 'topic2'
```

The main difference between the two scenarios (e.g. `merge1` and `merge2`) is that `merge2^` refers to the merge base of `topic2` and `master` (before the merge) and `merge1^` is a unique, non-merge commit. I'm not sure if this intermediate commit being between the merge base and the merge commit matters, but I can't think of anything else it could be. Can anyone explain this difference in behavior?

What I expect is that `git show merge1` does not show a diff. As far as I am concerned, `git show merge2` output is correct, and `git show merge1` is incorrect (buggy).

Git version is 2.22.0 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git show` produces combined diffs by default.  (This is an improvement over `git log -p`, which, for merge commits, produces *no diffs at all* by default!)

Combined diffs are documented—somewhat poorly in my opinion—in two separate sections that show up in several of the various `git diff` command manual pages.  Here are the two critical sections from the `git diff-tree` documentation:

- [**diff format for merges**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#_diff_format_for_merges)
- [**combined diff format**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#_combined_diff_format)

The first section, near the bottom, has this caveat:

> Note that *combined diff* lists only files which were modified from all parents.

This should probably be boldface, 18-point font, and/or blinking and *not* quite so far from the *second* section that tells you how to read the output.  (The `-p` description has its own section between these two.  Also, the first section is talking about the mode-line stuff, but the fact that many files are omitted entirely applies to the second section, it's just not mentioned *in* the second section.)

I think the goal here is to make the default `git show` output show you where someone might have had to do conflict resolution.  That's usually a good idea, but sometimes you really want `git show -m`, which just shows one diff against the first parent, and then a second diff against the second parent.

Answer (score 0):

`git show` will show diff stuff if there was a conflict resolution.

Comment: Can you point me to any official documentation that explains this in more detail?